# Predicting future x values using polynomial regression

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, polynomials

I have made a function to predict a future y value using polynomial Regression. I need to make a function to predict a future x value how would I go about doing this?
This is what I have for y:

```
def predict_y():
    """Now we can use the information we have gathered to predict future values."""
    import numpy

    x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 22]
    y = [100, 90, 80, 60, 60, 55, 60, 65, 70, 70, 75, 76, 78, 79, 90, 99, 99, 100]

    my_model = numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(x, y, 3))
    y_value = my_model(17)  # 17 is time of day

    print("y :", y_value)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to make a function to predict a future x value how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`np.roots`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 22])
y = np.array([100, 90, 80, 60, 60, 55, 60, 65, 70, 70, 75, 76, 78, 79, 90, 99, 99, 100])

def predict_x(yn):
    roots = np.roots(np.polyfit(x, y - yn, deg=3))
    reals = abs(roots.imag) < 1e-6
    return roots.real[reals]
```

Test:

```
# For y=100, there are 3 solutions:
# x <- 1 without imaginary part
# x <- 22 with imaginary part +/- 1j
>>> predict_x(100)
array([0.96479053])

# For x=70, there are also 3 solutions with only real part
>>> predict_x(70)
array([27.66728164, 12.44388509,  4.19269035])
```

Comment: Does it what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the help, however the function doesn't work.
             
roots = np.roots(np.polyfit(x, y - yn, deg=3))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: You have to convert your list as numpy array as I did especially for y or use a comprehension to subtract yn to each element of y.

Comment: I fixed the program using your solution. From my understanding, is the middle element of the list the x value?